# MATLAB : Solving non-polynomial equations numerically

Tags: matlab, equation, solver

I have an equation:

```
9.73*10^(3)*(x-y)/log((296-y)/(296-x)) - 15 = 0

1/(1+((x^2-3^2)*(x-3))^(-1))((x-y)/(log((x-3)/(y-3)))
```

and I tried to solve it for x in terms of y. I tried doing it both symbolically and numerically using functions solve, fsolve and vpasolve. Both failed (symbolic solver returned a conditional solution and the numerical one returned an empty object).

Any tips on solving an equation like that?

Edit:

Actual code (note some extra constants in the equations, but the overall structure of the equations remains the same) and the output:

```
syms T_i T_o
eqn1 = (9.73*10^(3))*(T_o - T_i)/(log((296-T_i)/(296-T_o))) - 15 == 0;
eqn2 = 1/(1.65*10^(-5)+1/(0.9*5.67*10^(-8)*0.01*(T_o^3-3^3)*(T_o-3)))*...
       ((T_o-T_i)/log((T_o-3)/(T_i-3))) - 15 == 0;

S = vpasolve([eqn1,eqn2],[T_o,T_i])
```

OUTPUT:

```
S = 

T_o:   [0x1 sym]
T_i:   [0x1 sym]
```

i.e. no solutions were found. I tried solving for one variable and then insert it into the second equation, but this also fails (gives a conditional solution):

```
syms T_i T_o
eqn  = (T_o - T_i)/(log((296-T_i)/(296-T_o))) == 15;
solT = solve(eqn,T_i);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Warning: The solutions are valid under the following conditions:
15*wrightOmega(T_o/15 - log(15/(T_o - 296)) - 296/15) + 296 ~= T_o.
To include parameters and conditions in the solution,
specify the 'ReturnConditions' option. 
> In solve>warnIfParams (line 507)
  In solve (line 356)
```

Comment: Show your code that failed

Comment: @SardarUsama I added the code and the resulting outputs now.

Comment: Also your `fsolve` trial may be relevant. An analytical solution may not exist.